# Create portable Elementary OS USB for UEFI and BIOS

Tags: boot, system-installation, grub, uefi, elementary-os

I want to create a personal portable Elementary OS install on a 64GB USB stick.

My personal PC is UEFI with GPT, dual boot Arch Linux and Windows 10. I want to be able to boot the USB to recover my UEFI computer in the future and use the same USB on a school BIOS MBR computer.

I have a separate 4GB USB I can use to install the OS to the 128GB USB from my UEFI computer.

Once I get the Elementary OS iso on the 4GB USB, how do I proceed to install it to the 128GB USB?

(Please try to keep it simple, I'm bad at partitioning)

Edit 1: Also, I'm not willing to disconnect the hard drive for the process if possible, is this dangerous? I have a UEFI grub dual boot on the hard drive of the PC I'm doing the installation from.

Edit 2: From watching an [Elementary OS installation video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljVbSBM9cAo), I figured out you can create a new `/boot/efi` for the USB so I don't need to disconnect my hard drive. This does not solve the BIOS problem, as I still don't know how to make the USB bootable on Legacy BIOS too.

Comment: If it would be OK with a persistent live system, you can use [mkusb-dus](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/) and it will be easy. Otherwise it might be complicated, if you have no computer, where you can unplug, disconnect or otherwise disable the internal drive. Maybe the [best instructions to create an installed system in USB is found here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step).

Comment: If you post the same text as an answer, I will mark it as an answer. Thank you. I'll use the tutorial you linked and not the persistent system way.

Comment: *Done* and good luck with yout portable installed system :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Persistent live system

- If it would be OK with a persistent live system, you can use [mkusb-dus](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/) and it will be easy.

### Installed system in USB drive, bootable in UEFI and BIOS mode

- Otherwise it might be complicated, if you have no computer, where you can unplug, disconnect or otherwise disable the internal drive. Maybe the [best instructions to create an installed system in USB is found here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step).